# How do I get a "Delete" key with an Apple Bluetooth keyboard on Windows?

Tags: keyboard, windows, bluetooth

My Macbook died and I had to switch to my emergency backup machine, an [Intel NUC](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/overview.html) running Windows 10.

I can use my Apple bluetooth keyboard all right with it, but I can't get a <kbd>del</kbd> key. Normally this can be achieved by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>, but that doesn't seem to cut it now. Neither do any other combinations I've seen suggested (Ctrl+Fn+Backspace, Shift+Fn+Backspace, Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Fn+Backspace and combinations thereof).

Also I notice several other keys not working as expected. The <kbd>< ></kbd> key is mapped with <kbd>^°</kbd>, for example, and the other way 'round. All the major keys work, though, the keyboard layout in the system matches the layout of the keyboard (German).

How can I fix this?

Comment: What keyboard settings do you have in Windows 10?

Comment: It's the correct layout (German). I found a tool called Keyboard Layout Creator, which is said to come with a "German (Apple)" layout, but it doesn't run on Windows 10 (it needs an old version of .NET that I can't install).

Comment: Maybe you should try asking this in a forum for Windows?  It doesn't really have anything to do with Apple, there's nothing you can change about a keyboard.

Comment: @Tom probably the better way to go, yeah...